# port 8820 - what is it?

Tags: tcp, udp, layer4

I need to write a code, which communicates between 2 computers. 
I saw many people use port 8820 in their code when they want to communicate between computers.
I know the term port but What is port 8820?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**8820 is an unreserved port.**

I think, you are doing socket programming. You want to connect two PC. You want to transfer data.

**Socket = IP Address + Port Number.**

IP address is used to identity the PC. Port number is used to identity the process in that PC.

Each process runs in an unique port number. Port number is 16bit address. When we want process to process communication, we use port number. This works at transport layer. Please read transport layer in TCP/IP model.

There are some Port numbers which are reserved such as port number 80 is used for HTTP. 20 and 21 for FTP. 22 for ssh.

**Port Number Ranges**

TCP, UDP, UDP-Lite, SCTP, and DCCP use 16-bit namespaces for their
   port number registries.  The port registries for all of these
   transport protocols are subdivided into three ranges of numbers
   [RFC1340], and Section 8.1.2 describes the IANA procedures for each
   range in detail:

o  the System Ports, also known as the Well Known Ports, from 0-1023
      (assigned by IANA)

o  the User Ports, also known as the Registered Ports, from 1024-
      49151 (assigned by IANA)

o  the Dynamic Ports, also known as the Private or Ephemeral Ports,
      from 49152-65535 (never assigned)

Of the assignable port ranges (System Ports and User Ports, i.e.,
   port numbers 0-49151), individual port numbers are in one of three
   states at any given time:

o  Assigned: Assigned port numbers are currently assigned to the
      service indicated in the registry.

o  Unassigned: Unassigned port numbers are currently available for
      assignment upon request, as per the procedures outlined in this
      document.

o  Reserved: Reserved port numbers are not available for regular
      assignment; they are "assigned to IANA" for special purposes.
      Reserved port numbers include values at the edges of each range,
      e.g., 0, 1023, 1024, etc., which may be used to extend these
      ranges or the overall port number space in the future.

In order to keep the size of the registry manageable, IANA typically
   only records the Assigned and Reserved service names and port numbers
   in the registry.  Unassigned values are typically not explicitly
   listed.  (There are very many Unassigned service names and
   enumerating them all would not be practical.)

As a data point, when this document was written, approximately 76% of
   the TCP and UDP System Ports were assigned, and approximately 9% of
   the User Ports were assigned.  (As noted, Dynamic Ports are never
   assigned.)

So you choose any port number which are not reserved.
Max port numbers is 2^16. Because port number is 16bit.

For example, You can use 5000, ...6800,...8821, 8822, ....,46789,...,65353 etc. Choose any unreserved port. Remember, port number in both PC should be same.

Comment: Most of ports 0-1000 are not reserved, they are system ports, many of which are assigned. Ports 0-1023 are system ports and ports 1024-49151 are user ports. Both these ranges are technically assigned ranges. The dynamic and/or private use range is 49152-65535. Feel free to reference [RFC 6335](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6335) and [RFC 8126](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8126) for more information. This answer is flawed.

Answer (score 4):

Port 8820 is unassigned.  You can see the official [IANA list here](ftp://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt).